# How can I troubleshoot R and tk on macOS?

Tags: macos, homebrew, x11, open-source

I am getting warnings and empty popup boxes when compiling and loading R packages that depend on tk. They say that tk was not installed correctly.

I am using homebrew, but I can't tell which package might provide a correct install of tk, or if it would conflict with the existing (but broken) installation.

What is the recommended way to install enough of tk on OSX so that an R package with tk as a dependency (e.g. [RNCEP](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RNCEP/index.html)) R will compile without giving this warning?

**Update**

Here is the warning that I get when trying to load an R package that depends on tk.tcl:

> ```
> Warning message:
> In fun(libname, pkgname) :
>   Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk8.5
> ```
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tk8.5
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts
>   ./lib/tk8.5 ./lib/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts ~/Library/Tcl/tk8.5
>   ~/Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Tcl/tk8.5
>   /Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /System/Library/Tcl/tk8.5
>   /System/Library/Tcl/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts
>   /System/Library/Tcl/8.5/tk8.5
>   /System/Library/Tcl/8.5/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts
>   ~/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5
>   ~/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts /Library/Frameworks/tk8.5
>   /Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/tk8.5/Resources/Scripts ./library

Comment: Are you using a specific version of R? Does [this article](https://www.nesono.com/node/355) yield a workable R install? Are you [asking an XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem and really just looking to get R installed by bypassing a tk error or is getting a full tk part of the main goal?

Comment: @bmike I've got a workable R install (installed as a .dmg downloaded from [Rstudio](www.rstudio.com), this is just giving me warnings and empty tk boxes). It started when I used brew to install inkscape and ghostscript (both of which require X11).

Comment: Try installing R from homebrew - as the package writers should have sorted out issue

Comment: @Abe does your comment mean that you had a working R before you installed inkscape and ghostscript?

Comment: @Mark yes, it did work. Would it be a problem to overwrite the existing installation of R? Do I need to uninstall?

Comment: How are you starting R?

Comment: @Mark Either with Rstudio, R, or Rscript.

Comment: I meant form the command line or as an app

Comment: @mark both command line (R, Rscript) and app (Rstudio).

Comment: Did you check if Tk was already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing tk from the [ActiveState ActiveTcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads) binaries. If you're on Mavericks, make sure that you install ActiveTcl 8.5.15.0 or greater, as there are some problems with earlier versions on Mavericks. Also, please note that ActiveTcl is not open-source software.